# How can I get X server to stop while installing nvidia's proprietary drivers on Arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, x11, drivers, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

I am currently in the process of immigrating to Arch Linux. I am trying to install the drivers, however it keeps telling me that "X server is running". I have looked everywhere and <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> just restarts Gnome before I even get the chance to log in to tty.

And X server is apparently still somehow running? I tried to kill X server, but the shortcut didn't work, and even in tty2 the error shows up, so how do i get rid of the X server? Does it have something to do with X11 the window manager? If so how do i  kill it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the whole service. Otherwise it will just start again, like you noticed.

Depending on which desktop manager you are running, you can use one of the following commands to do that from a terminal:

```
systemctl stop gdm      # for Gnome Display Manager
systemctl stop kdm      # for KDE Display Manager
systemctl stop lightdm  # for LightDM
systemctl stop lxdm     # for LXDM
```

The `systemctl` command usually requires root privileges, so you might get prompted to enter your password. Alternatively, you can prefix the command with `sudo`. For Gnome Desktop Manager, it would then look like this:

```
sudo systemctl stop gdm
```

If you don't have `sudo`, try switching to a root shell with `su -`, first. Then run the `systemctl` command without `sudo`:

```
username@mypc:~$ sudo systemctl stop gdm
bash: sudo: command not found
username@mypc:~$ su -
Password:
root@mypc:~# systemctl stop gdm
```

Also, instead of `systemctl`, you can try `service`:

```
root@mypc:~# systemctl stop gdm
root@mypc:~# service gdm stop
```

Comment: Sudo- Service command not found

Comment: Arch Linux doesn't have the `service` command. Use `sudo systemctl stop <servicename>` instead.

Comment: I have updated the answer to be more complete about `systemctl`, `service` as well as `sudo`.